# helm chart unable to see cloudwatch exporter in prometheus target

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm chart for running prometheus and cloudwatch exporter and follow all require documentation.

```
helm upgrade --install prometheus prometheus
```

in same cluster i installed cloudwatch exporter with

> helm upgrade --install ldm-emea-prometheus-cloudwatch-exporter 
>   ldm-emea-prometheus-cloudwatch-exporter

where i am installing these exporter from local file systam and rename it to ldm-emea-prometheus-cloudwatch-exporter since i will be having multiple accounts i need to manage

but when i installed both of these i am uanble to see target is listed in prometheus for cloudwatch exporter i defined.

do we have any way by which i can configure this in prometheus helm chart to pull details for this exporter

Comment: Do you have any service for this exporter? If so, did you added necessary annotation to the service for prometheus to discover it?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure out problem. I was using prometheus-operator helm chart which is missing

> scrape_timeout

bydefault it is 10seconds my cloudwatch exporter took more than 10 seconds. i started using prometheus helm chart instead of prometheus-operator as it is missing this configuration